# .Net Core Migration System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

This is my DbContext

```
public class DocumentStudioDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DocumentStudioDbContext(DbContextOptions<DocumentStudioDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Documents> Documents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_DatabaseSchema));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        Audit();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Audit();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void Audit()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is Documents && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((Documents)entry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        ((Documents)entry.Entity).UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run a migration, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   connectionString    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value,
>   String parameterName)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1
>   sqlServerOptionsAction)    at
>   DocumentStudio.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__1_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   options) in
>   C:\Users\amosa\source\repos\DotNetCore\DocumentStudio\DocumentStudio\Startup.cs:line
>   48    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(IServiceProvider
>   p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider
>   applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0(IServiceProvider
>   p)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__10`1.<AddCoreServices>b__10_1(IServiceProvider
>   p)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite
>   enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

My ConnectionString comes from the Environment Variables that is set in Visual Studio. I am unsure of how I can perform a migration.

What else do I need to do?

EDIT:

DbContext in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DocumentStudioDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString)));
```

EDIT2:

[image]

Managed to get the variable out from the environment variable

Comment: Show your `DbContext` registration in Statup class and the connection string in `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: My connectionstring is stored in the Environment Variables. I don;t use appsettings.json in the project.

Comment: Okay! Then show how are you getting `ConnectionSring` in Startup class during `DbContext` registration.

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString) is how I get the connection string. I tried setting it to a variable and it works.

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString)` this line is getting `ConnectionString` null. check it properly please! What is reason behind storing ConnectionString in environment variable instead of appsettings.json file?

Comment: I attached a screenshot. Its not null though. And also, I'm not using appsettings because that would be the only item in it. My other variables are environment variables.

Comment: I just tried to put a console writeline in my Startup.cs and you're right. the connectionstring is null. But why doesn't it read from the environment variable?

Comment: I have no idea as I have never used environment variable for storing connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <configuration>

          <connectionStrings>
              <add name="DocumentStudioDb"
                connectionString="Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DocumentStudioDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
                   </connectionStrings>
   </configuration>
```

/////write this code in your context

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder   optionsBuilder)
               {
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DocumentStudioDb"]  .ConnectionString);
                }
```